# Git/Gitflow different features in the same file

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow

Recently I've started to use `gitflow` and I really like its feature methodology. Mostly I do something like this: I start a new feature, I implement its logic in a separate file, I `git add > commit` etc. Then I finish my feature and I merge back do `develop`. No problems at all.

But after some time I experienced some problems. For example I have a file `FormMain.cs` which is basically like a `Controller` for my GUI in `WinForms`. So there are many events like `buttonABC_Click` or `buttonXYZ_Click`.

So let's say I only have two buttons on my GUI (but very important ones) -> ABC and XYZ. I want to implement a logic for clicking button ABC. No problem. I start a new feature, I do some commits. And if I finish it, push, merge and so on, there is no problem with starting to work on feature for button XYZ.

But if I don't finish the feature -> f.e. it needs some tests, or it even has to somehow work with the logic for clicking button XYZ, I don't `finish` the feature. And here comes trouble. If I start a new feature I basically start it from `develop` (which is still not merged with `feature/buttonABC`). So I don't have any code which I previously written for buttonABC here on `feature/buttonXYZ`. And then if I f.e want to finish `feature/buttonXYZ` -> there's no problem, it will work. But then if I want to finish `feature/buttonABC` -> there will be problem with merge, cuz on `feature/buttonABC` the `buttonXYZ_Click` function is empty, but on the previously merged `develop` (with `feature/buttonXYZ`) there's some code, so we have a merge conflict.

So my question here would be: Could I somehow fix that problem? Or maybe I shouldn't do multiple features in one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you outline should not lead to a merge conflict; in fact it's exactly the sort of thing merging is designed to do routinely.

So you start work (from `develop`) on `ABC`, and later you start work (from `develop`) on `XYZ`.

```
            X -- Y <--(featureXYZ)
           /
x -- x -- D <--(develop)
           \
            A -- B <--(featureABC)
```

Neither branch has the work from the other branch - that's what branching is about.

You finish up `XYZ` and merge it.

```
            X -- Y -- Z <--(featureXYZ)
           /           \
x -- x -- D ----------- M1 <--(develop)
           \          
            A -- B <--(featureABC)
```

Now you finish `ABC` and want to merge it, too, to get

```
            X -- Y -- Z<--(featureXYZ)
           /           \
x -- x -- D ----------- M1 -- M2<--(develop)
           \                 /
            A ----- B ----- C <--(featureABC)
```

Now it's true that `featureABC` doesn't have code in the `XYZ` function.  But more importantly, `featureABC` didn't *change* the `XYZ` function.  So here's how the merge goes down:

Just before the merge you have

```
            X -- Y -- Z<--(featureXYZ)
           /           \
x -- x -- D ----------- M1 <--(develop)
           \                 
            A ----- B ----- C <--(featureABC)
```

You've checked out `develop` and you say `git merge featureABC`.  So git says wants to identify three commits: one as "ours", one as "theirs", and one as the "base".  You're on `develop`, so `develop` is "ours".  And you said to merge in `featureABC`, so `featureABC` is "theirs".

The merge base is (more or less) the most recent common ancestor of "ours" and "theirs".  Looking at our graph, we can see that's `D` - the `develop` commit from before either branch was created.

So then git is going to calculate "our changes" - the difference between "base" and "ours", which is "add code to function `XYZ`".  Then it will find "their changes" - the difference between "base" and "theirs", which is "add code to function `ABC`".

Now it will try to apply both "our changes" and "their changes" to the "base", and the result of that will be the merge result.  There is a conflict *only if* one of "our changes" touches the same code as one of "their changes".

Well "our changes" add code to `XYZ` but say nothing about `ABC`; and "their changes" add code to `ABC` but say nothing about `XYZ`.  So there is no conflict, and the merge works just like it's supposed to.

Comment: Sorry for my absence. You're totally right. Thanks for the clarification!